# How to add a metafield to a customer in Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm creating a signup form on my Shopify store, for customers. I'm willing to have them enter their basic credentials (email) plus additional info. I'd like to have that additional info stored in the customer's metafields.

I've seen here:  http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/capture-additional-information-in-the-account-registration-form    I can ask customers for additional information in the form of notes, but found no path to insert metafields.

I think this is possible, but I don't know how I could do.

Could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

[See here](http://www.shopify.com/technology/3032322-new-feature-metafields#axzz2jM2tmu7Z):

> For the time being, you can only add these metafields and edit them using the Shopify API. Some time from now, we will make it possible for a shop owner to manage them from the admin interface.

As far as I am aware [this is still the case](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/metafields-in-admin-area-when-110023), and you must use the API to create/access metafields. See the [Shopify doco on Metafields here](http://docs.shopify.com/api/metafield).
Alternatively, [there are apps](http://apps.shopify.com/metafields2) that can help with the process.

Comment: Still the case :(

Answer (score 1):

Since it isn't possible to create a new area in the admin to hold the user's information, so technically you can't add a metafield to a customer.

But you can add a new field on registration page as a customer note.
All additional collected information will be displayed on the customer account page.

Add following lines inside `{% form 'create_customer' %}` and  `{% endform %}` to add your custom field. Replace the [Label] with your own unique label.

```
<label>The text shown as label in the form</label>
<input type="text" name="customer[note][Label]" placeholder="Placeholder text" />
```

The attribute name="customer[note][Label]" is essential here. With it, the information will be submitted as a customer note. Without it, nothing will be submitted.

Comment: How would you reference the attribute when retrieving the data?  
For example: "{{ customer.note }}" references the whole note, how to reference the part of it we marked with [Label]?