# Can I update shopify customer metafields now through theme file?

Tags: shopify

I'm wondering if there's now a way to update customer metafields from a Shopify theme. I found this question [How to add a metafield to a customer in Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706718/how-to-add-a-metafield-to-a-customer-in-shopify) and the documentation still states to use notes.

I noticed that question was quite out of date now and also Shopify admin has editable fields now for customer metafields.

Is there a way to capture data in the registration form to populate customer metafields? Or do I have to use notes?
Below is what I tried?

```
 <input
        type="text"
        name="customer[metafields][mobile]"
        id="RegisterForm-mobile"
        aria-required="true"
        {% if form.errors contains 'mobile' %}
          aria-invalid="true"
          aria-describedby="RegisterForm-mobile-error"
        {% endif %}
        placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.mobile' | t }}"
      >
      <label for="RegisterForm-mobile">
        {{ 'customer.register.mobile' | t }}
      </label>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit late here, however I thought I'd leave a link to [FieldsRaven](https://apps.shopify.com/fieldsraven) app here. The app is perfect for your use case, here is a "Customer registration with custom attributes" [example](https://docs.fieldsraven.app/example-features/customer-registration-with-custom-attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer is yes, you can update metafields from a theme. Also a short answer, you cannot do this without using an App. Short answer as to why this is? **Only an App has permissions** to change data like metafields in a store (other than provided forms like the ones used to capture a customer's info such as address). These forms are not a gateway drug to metafields.

The typical approach in your only option is to set up an App with an App Proxy, allowing JS calls to be securely made with that precious data from the store. That is the best you can do. In fact, it is all you can do.

Comment: cool, thanks David. Figured that might be the case. I'm coming at this from Salesforce commerce - I'm finding there's a quite a few constraints and workarounds needed in Shopify dev!

Comment: Every system has zits, warts and bad gas at times and in places. It's good this way! I once had to work with Salesforce. Was terrible. Enterprise crap! But they own the best SaaS company ever in Heroku. So I give them that. Let it be!